# Can I choose between default-initalisation and value-initialisaion or all or part of an array?

Tags: c++, value-initialization

Since C++2003 we have value-initialisation as well as default-initialisation. Meaning that:

```
struct Foo {
    int i;
    std :: string s;
};

Foo f1;          // f1.s is default-constructed, f1.i is uninitialised
Foo f2 = Foo (); // f1.s is default-constructed, f1.i is zero
```

Right?

Now suppose I have this class

```
class Bar : public Foo {
    int n;
    Foo f [SIZE];
public:
    Bar ();
};
```

When I write the constructor for `Bar`, I may want to default- or value-initialise either the parent class or the `f[]` member. I think the choice for initialising the parent is simply:

```
Bar :: Bar () : Foo (), n (-1) {} // Parent is value-initialised (Foo::i is zero)
Bar :: Bar () : n (-1)         {} // Parent is default-initialised (Foo::i is undefined)
```

But what about the `f[]` member?

- How do I default-initialise all members?
- How do I value-initialise all members?
- If I use C++11 initializer lists, what happens if the initializer list has a different size than `SIZE`?

Comment: Please avoid spaces around `::`.

Comment: Why? I like it, it's easier to read.

Comment: @spraff And yet you use PascalCaseWhereWordsRunTogether?

Comment: For types, yes, for variables, no, and I don't give them LongNamesWhichSufferReadibilityProblems. But let's *not* have a style war in the comments.

Comment: In the first example _i_ will remain uninitialized in both default initialization and from-copy initialization, the difference is that in from-copy initialization _i_ will be initialized with garbage from the temporary Foo's member _i_. The from-copy initialization the way you use it is generally slower as it may result in temporary object creation (most compilers won't create extra copy though).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, according to standard value-initialization seems to be the process of calling whatever form of user-defined default constructor there or to zero-initialize objects which don't have a default constructor (see 8.5 [decl.init] paragraph 7:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is called.
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized; — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

In this sense you can value initialize your array member since C++1998 using `f()` in the member initializer list. If you want to use specific values, you need to use C++2011 with an initializer list e.g. `f({ 1, 2, 3 })`. If there are fewer arguments than there are elements, the remaining elements are value initialized. Actually, the are initialized from an empty initializer list (8.5.1 [dcl.init.aggr] paragraph 7):

> If there are fewer initializer-clauses in the list than there are members in the aggregate, then each member
> not explicitly initialized shall be initialized from an empty initializer list.

... and this initialization from an empty initializer list means according to 8.5.4 [dcl.init.list] paragraph 3, bullet 7:

> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.